# How to call MinGW (not MSYS) commands from CMake ExternalProject_add?

Tags: c++, windows, bash, cmake, mingw

I want to allow building of my project under MinGW. My project requieres [FFTW build](http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html). My dependency does not use CMake to generate make files. To build it I need to be able to call bash:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

In cmake [ExternalProject_add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) I can add `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, `BUILD_COMMAND` and `INSTALL_COMMAND`. I wonder how to specify it to run MinGW bash console to run this commands?

Comment: If your project requires another project to be installed, then my recommendation is that you *document* this requirement, and have the user install that dependency himself. Then it's up to the user to install from a package manager or from source. Just about the only time you need to distribute and build dependencies, at leas that I can think of, is if you're developing a proprietary system that depends on specific versions of some library.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Only to document is a way to make life of windows developer even harder...